# Arrow key to move cursor down one line in text editor stopped working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editor

I can no longer use just the down arrow keyboard key to move the cursor down one line in the text editor. Using arrow keys to move up, left, and right still works fine. How could this have broken, and how can I fix this?

I have closed and re-opened VS, but that did not fix the issue.

Right before this started happening, I was remapping some of the keyboard shortcuts under Options -> Keyboard. I deleted a bunch of unused shortcuts, added some new ones, and changed some. Is it possible that there was a shortcut just for moving the cursor around that I inadvertently deleted? I looked, but I don't see any shortcuts that might fit that description.

Comment: Tools > Import/Export > Reset

Comment: No. Why is this always the answer given? I don't want to reset all changes, because then I would have to redo all of the hundreds of other settings changes that have been made. Since I likely won't remember exactly how I changed every setting, I'd be stuck in an infinite loop of being told to just reset everything the moment something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, **Edit.LineDown** command should have Down Arrow assigned to it in the **Text Editor** scope:

[image]

You may need to reassign the shortcut if it is broken.